# Android cannot resolve add symbol?

Tags: java, android

I am beginning to develep an android application.
I would like to show a "history call list".

To beginning, I created a java class to initialize my "HistoryCall" object.
This object contains:
- CallDate: The date the call occured, in milliseconds since the epoch.
- CallNumber: The phone number
- Type: The type of the call (incoming, outgoing or missed).

How to insert data in my HistoryCall object ?

My code:

```
package com.example.test.test2;

//IMPORT
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class HistoryCall {

//Init object
    public HistoryCall(long CallDate, Int CallNumber, Int Type) {}

//Insert data into object
    ArrayList<HistoryCall> HistoryCallList =  new ArrayList<HistoryCall>();
            HistoryCallList.add(5607059900000L, 0102030405, 1);
            HistoryCallList.add(5607059900003L, 0602030405, 1);
};
```

I have several problems:

- "cannot resolve symbol add" ?? I don't know what that means.
- error:  expected HistoryCallList.add(5607059900000L, 0102030405, 1);
- error: illegal start of type HistoryCallList.add(5607059900000L, 0102030405, 1);

My next step is to show this list in application

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method which matches with three parameters like this. So you got error.

You can add a item in list, but not anything you want.

```
HistoryCallList.add(new HistoryCall(5607059900003L,0602030405,1));
```

Make sure you have all fields in constructor of  model.

```
public class HistoryCall {
    long CallDate; 
    int CallNumber; 
    int Type;
    public HistoryCall(long CallDate, int CallNumber, int Type) {
       this.CallDate = CallDate;
       this.CallNumber = CallNumber;
       this.Type = Type;
    }
// getters setters here
};
```

**Suggestion:**

- `Int` is nothing in Java, use `int` or `Integer`.
- Use small case for variables name in Java. Read **[Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/codeconventions-135099.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Add the items like this:

```
HistoryCallList.add(new HistoryCall(5607059900000L, 0102030405, 1));
```

This list holds HistoryCall objects, that's why you must instantiate one and then add it

Answer (score 1):

You need create an `HistoryCall` object before add it into the list:

```
HistoryCallList.add(new HistoryCall(5607059900003L,0602030405,1));
```

And the constructor should accept `int` type, not `Int`.

And this piece of code, should in a block, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Insert data into object
    ArrayList<HistoryCall> HistoryCallList = new ArrayList<HistoryCall>();
    HistoryCallList.add(new HistoryCall(5607059900003L, 0602030405, 1));
}
```

And the varibales name is better to begin with lower case:

```
ArrayList<HistoryCall> historyCallList = new ArrayList<HistoryCall>();
```